# Java web start : To increase system memory more than 2 GB

Tags: java, jvm, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, java-web-start

We are using Java webstart in our project, Since the UI has more data to handle, we want the system (client system where java webstart would start) memory to be increased to 4 GB through JVM args

We have this below setting in JNLP file.

```
<resources>
    <java max-heap-size="1363148800" java-vm-args="-D64 -Xrs -Xmx1300M -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10 - version="1.6+"/>
```

When we increased the heapsize from 1300 M to 4GB, still the Java webstart is allocating only 1300 M

When i browsed on this, I got to know that Java web start will use only 32 bit JRE and will not support 64 JRE (even if we specify -D64 parameter)

How to over come this ? How to allocate 4GB memory to Java webstart ?

Comment: If you're launching from a browser it probably needs a 64bit browser + 64bit java plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Java 64bit installed then double-clicking on your jnlp file should open the 64bit version (running it from browser may use 32-bit so don't do that for now). So try this and if double-clicking on .jnlp file did not start 64bit java then there is a problem with your java installation so try uninstalling all your Java versions and then install them again fresh.

As for allocating 4G memory try this:

```
<java version="1.6+" initial-heap-size="4G" max-heap-size="4G"/>
```

Comment: this is not working. not more than 1.3G is allocated. What I understand from these links is, 64 bit is not supported for Java web start. Is that true ?http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources    http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#64bit_components

Comment: That's not true. Where does it say on that page that 64bit is not support for webstart? I myself run my webstart application from 64bit webstart all the time. You don't need to add anything to jnlp for that. If there is both 32bit and 64bit Java installed, Java automatically chooses 64bit to run your jnlp file when you double-click on MyProgram.jnlp file.

Comment: I can't allocate memory more than 1.3 GB, am looking to allocate 4GB

Comment: Please look at this link where it is said that Java westat doesnt support 64 bit http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#64bit_components

Comment: It says "Java Plug-in" doesn't support 64 bit. However Java does support 64bit. So you have to make sure to run the program without using "Java Plug-in" and as I already mentioned, the way to do that is by double-clicking on your jnlp file directly (in Windows) instead of running it though the browser.

Comment: Thanks Saeid. I did. But still i couldn't increase the memory. Only 1.3 I can allocate. Even though i allocate 4 GB, it gets reset-ted automatically to 1.3 GB

Comment: What happens when you try different memory sizes? Try allocating 3.9, 1.5 and 1.2 GB of memory and see which of those cases behave correctly?